# How do Multy get a sample of Elasticsearch php?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, mono

Harness the Elasticsearch client in php.
How can I find a lot of documents in the ES, for id,'s equal to "WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,9)" in SQL?
For mono get I do so

```
$ params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id'
  ];

  $ response = $ client-> get ($ params);
```

how to get some records?
I tried so, but it does not work

```
$ params = [[
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id'
  ]
  [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id2'
  ]];

  $ response = $ client-> mget ($ params);
```

and so

```
$ params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => array ('my_id', 'my_id2')
  ];

  $ response = $ client-> mget ($ params);
```

The API is PHP has only https: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_getting_documents.html

That's kind of it, only CURL request https: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-multi-get.html

Who worked with ES, help please!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to use the [`ids`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-filter.html) filter, like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'ids' => [ 
                        'values' => ['my_id', 'my_id2'] 
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];


$results = $client->search($params);
```

**UPDATE**

If you absolutely want to use `mget`, then you should do it like this:

```
$ params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => ['ids' => ['my_id', 'my_id2']]
  ];

  $ response = $ client-> mget ($ params);
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this out?

Comment: But Why is not mget working. It is supposed to be working with 'docs' key right ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_retrieving_multiple_documents.html

Comment: Thanks alot. Where do you find this ? As Elastic Search PHP client as a very little documentation

Comment: There is also some document in the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/37a572b99b443f907cd3b0a2801fcdea3cbd9d31/docs/build/Elasticsearch/Client.asciidoc#Elasticsearch_Clientmget_mget)

Answer (score 0):

Read source code \vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Client.php and mget function. you should do it like this:

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'index',
        'type' => 'type',
        'body' => array('ids' => array('id1', 'id2'))
      ];
    
    $response = $ client-> mget ($ params);
    foreach ($response ['docs'] as $doc)
    {
        $source = $doc['_source'];
    }
```

Comment: Please consider explaining WHY the OP should do it LIKE THAT, so that all of us could understand better and learn from you~

Comment: Thanks for your advice@Simas Joneliunas

Answer (score -1):

Just add below line during insert

```
"refresh"=> true
```